# google analytics users flow graph for mobile?

Tags: google-analytics

On the GA web console left navigation area there's a handy Audience report named "Users Flow". This seems to be present only for my web application and is missing for my mobile app analytics. Is this not supported or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it takes 24 hours for this section of the reports to show up after the initial submission of events. after 24 hours the section appears.